# Expand $z^4\cos(z-1)$ around $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Expand  $z^4\cos(z-1)$ around $z=1$ to Laurent series

We take $w=z-1$

$$(w+1)^4\cos(w)=(w+1)^4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{w^{2n}}{2n!}=(w^4+4w^3+6w^2+4w+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{w^{2n}}{2n!}$$

How should I continue?

Comment: Continue by correcting your $(w-1)$ into $(w+1)$

Comment: $z=w+1$! no?....

Comment: Aside from the $z=w+1$, it looks fine so far. If you want to get it in the form $\sum a_nw^n$, you need to distribute the product and collect like powers/terms.

Comment: After following the previous suggestion, you should get $1+4 (z-1)+\frac{11}{2} (z-1)^2+2 (z-1)^3-\frac{47}{24}
   (z-1)^4-\frac{11}{6} (z-1)^5-\frac{181}{720} (z-1)^6+\frac{29}{180}
   (z-1)^7+\cdots$ There is no “pretty” answer, is that's what you want.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos if there is a better way of course I would like to learn

Comment: Your denominators in the series are slightly wrong -- they must be $(2n)!$, not $2n!$.

Answer (score 0):

To expand $f (z) =z^4\cos (z-1)$ arround $z=1$, we expand $g (z)=f (z+1) $ arround $z=0$ and we get $f (z)=g (z-1 )$.

$$g (z)=(1+z)^4\cos (z) $$
$$=(1+4z+6z^2+4z^3+z^4)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n $$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_ {n-4}+4a_{n-3}+6a_{n-2}+4a_{n-1}+a_n)z^n $$

with
$$a_{2p}=(-1)^p\frac {1}{(2p)!} $$
$$a_{2p+1}=0$$
and
$$j <0\implies a_j=0$$

replace $z $ by $z-1$ in $g (z) $ to get $f (z) $.